# Is there a repository for R Studio so I can apt-get upgrade it periodically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rstudio

[This link provides the download instructions for R Studio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/). Unfortunatley I do not see any reference to repositories, `apt-get`, or anything of the sort.

Most of my Linux programs auto-update simply by issuing the commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

How do I get R Studio into this `apt-get upgrade` universe? I don't like manually downloading and updating through their website and Ubuntu's *software center* on a monthly basis. Too much of a pain.